# Как предотвратить крэш памяти?

Tags: vue.js

Была задача автоматически обновлять список заказов на странице. Воспользовался самым банальным решением с использованием setInterval, но вскоре после открытия страницы хром начинает ругаться на то, что щас будет крэш памяти (Paused before potential out of memory crash)

```js
data () {
  return {
    interval: null,
    orders: []
  }
},
methods: {
  refreshData () {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
    Vue.http.get('orders').then(response => {
      this.orders = response.body
      this.interval = setInterval(this.refreshData, 3000)
    }
  },
},
created: function () {
  this.interval = setInterval(this.refreshData, 3000)
},
beforeDestroy () {
  clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

Подскажите куда копать, что делать? Первый раз с таким столкнулся.

Comment: Очищать нужно предыдущий таймер перед выполнением `Vue.http.get` и запускать новый по окончанию асинхронного запроса.

Comment: Сделал так. Хром больше не ругается. Но через какое-то время всеравно сожрал всю память.

Comment: В вопрос добавьте ваши изменения. Такой вариант https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket или заморочек много?

Comment: Изменения добавил. Сейчас надо запустить это все без сокетов, но через какое-то время буду переделывать под RabbitMQ.

Comment: Судя по нынешнему коду, вам проще перейти на setTimeout

Comment: `Через некоторое время сожрал память` - Убедитесь, что Developer Tools(консоль) закрыта(Она хранит в себе всю информацию обо всех выполненных запросах). Нажмите Shift+Esc, чтобы убедиться в том, кто именно выжирает память.

Comment: @vp_arth вы имеете ввиду после каждого запроса запускать setTimeout? А в чем разница на практике?
А Shift+Esc - что должен сделать? мне не знакома эта комбинация.

Comment: Shift+Esc в браузере открывает диспетчер процессов с отображением потребляемой памяти и ресурсов процессора.